# R DEoptim - apply asset weight constraints on a portfolio optimization

Tags: r, optimization

I am using DEoptim to create an optimization framework for asset allocation. I use a custom objective function that minimizes tail risk subject to returns threshold.

How can I set-up a constraint that limits allocation to a set of assets? For a N member optimization I want to limit the weight of specific n (n subset of N) members as a constraint.

How do I do it? Vignette on "Large scale portfolio optimization with DEoptim" is helpful but does not answer this question. Any guidance / example would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. Did you find any solutions or helpful link or articles? Thanks!

Comment: No, I have not and it is still an outstanding item that I'm looking for solutions / workarounds etc.  This limitation makes the use of package relatively impractical.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try integrating the constraint into the objective function?

For instance if you minimize

```
Tail Risk Measure + scaling factor*(max(0,Subset n weight - threshold weight))
```

then you would be penalizing the solutions with excess weights for this subset. You would of course need to tweak the scaling factor to ensure it does not become more important than the risk measure itself.